# My HAproxy container exits every time i want to run it

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, haproxy

My HAproxy container exits every time i try to run it .

I have tried to run it without --d to see why it exited and I get the following output:

```
$ sudo docker run  --name=hapr -p 80:80 -v /haproxy/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/  haproxy
```

I get this output:

```
HA-Proxy version 2.1.4 2020/04/02 - https://haproxy.org/ Status: stable branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q1 2021. Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.1.4.html Usage : haproxy [-f <cfgfile|cfgdir>]* [ -vdVD ] [ -n <maxconn> ] [ -N <maxpconn> [ -p <pidfile> ] [ -m <max megs> ] [ -C <dir> ] [-- <cfgfile>* -v displays version ; -vv shows known build options. -d enters debug mode ; -db only disables background mode. -dM[<byte>] poisons memory with <byte> (defaults to 0x50) -V enters verbose mode (disables quiet mode) -D goes daemon ; -C changes to <dir> before loading files. -W master-worker mode. -q quiet mode : don't display messages -c check mode : only check config files and exit -n sets the maximum total # of connections (uses ulimit -n) -m limits the usable amount of memory (in MB) -N sets the default, per-proxy maximum # of connections (0) -L set local peer name (default to hostname) -p writes pids of all children to this file -de disables epoll() usage even when available -dp disables poll() usage even when available -dS disables splice usage (broken on old kernels) -dG disables getaddrinfo() usage -dR disables SO_REUSEPORT usage -dr ignores server address resolution failures -dV disables SSL verify on servers side -sf/-st [pid ]* finishes/terminates old pids. -x <unix_socket> get listening sockets from a unix socket -S <bind>[,<bind options>...] new master CLI
```

If I list the container I get the following message:

```
$ docker container ls -a

Exited (1) 3 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my problem , If someone get same problem . 
So just you should have the full path in your command . 
instaed of

```
$ sudo docker run  --name=hapr -p 80:80 -v /haproxy/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/  haproxy
```

use

```
$ sudo docker run  --name=hapr -p 80:80 -v /home/ubuntu/haproxy/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/  haproxy
```

also you should have haproxy.cfg allready in your host .

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [official HAproxy page on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy) you could see that you need to have the `haproxy.cfg` in to the path `/haproxy/`. If not, HAproxy can not start.

> Note that your host's /path/to/etc/haproxy folder should be populated with a file named haproxy.cfg. If this configuration file refers to any other files within that folder then you should ensure that they also exist (e.g. template files such as 400.http, 404.http, and so forth).

There is the [official HAproxy documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/) about the haproxy.cfg.

To continue, you need to stop and delete the current container:

```
$ docker stop CONTAINER
$ docker rm CONTAINER
```

And created again.